# Jqgrid: get count of filter results without reloading grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have placed a row of buttons above my grid that apply certain filters to the grid in their onclick event:

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid("setGridParam",{
    postData: {filters: myFilterArray},
    search: true
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

I want the buttons to display the number of rows the respective query will return at page load, before they have been clicked (just like: "Pending: 115", "Error: 238", and so on).
The only way I found to do this so far is to call a method inside $(document).ready(function() {  }) that applies every button's filter, inserts the result of

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
```

into the respective button with jquery's .html() method, calls "setGridParam" again with postData: {filters: null} and reloads the grid again.

This is quite slow, the user has to wait unnecessarily for the the grid to load. Is there a way to get the result count of a certain query without actually applying it?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the number of rows a given query will return, without the grid actually going out, querying the DB, then populating the grid?

Only way I can think of is to perform some AJAX calls prior to creating the grid, then append that count that the query returns, to your button text.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'countQuery.php', // not sure which language you are working in, but the file that will actually run the query and return the counts
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#buttonPending").text("Pending: " + data.pendingCount);
        $("#buttonError").text("Error: " + data.errorCount);
    }
});
```

Comment: The datatype the grid uses is "jsonstring" and the "datastr" is provided by a java bean (inserted with server side javascript).
My original thought was that perhaps I could avoid further calls to the server by querying the data on the client side, where it is already loaded - of course that only makes sense if the client side queries don't take so much time. Querying the backend DB again is of course an obvious solution; it would just be very convenient to use the same filter-array for getting the result counts and then acutally filtering the grid when the button is clicked :-)